# Limit Comparison Test: can it be made stronger?

Tags: sequences-and-series

most versions of  LCT go something like this:

> Blockquote If $a_n, b_n>0$ and $\lim\frac{a_n}{b_n}=L$ where $0<L<\infty$  then $\sum a_n$ converges iff $\sum b_n$ converges

now I have seen counter examples that show all the bad things that can  happen if "$a_n, b_n>0$" is relaxed..  but consider the  following example $a_n=\frac1{n^4}$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{3-n^4}$. Seems to me, the convergence of $a_n$ says a lot about the convergence of $b_n$ yet LCT can not be applied as stated above... Could we replace  "$a_n, b_n>0$" with just "$b_n>0$ OR $a_n>0$" and allow L to be any non zero real number. This would elegantly cover examples such as the one stated above... [i know the above example could also be covered by looking at $-b_n$, then arguing that $\sum b_n$ conveges when $\sum cb_n$ converges etc etc.. but seems not as graceful..]  am i missing something here?  thx for your thoughts.

Comment: If $b_n > 0$ and $L \ne 0$, then $a_n$'s has the same sign for sufficiently large $n$'s.

Comment: Yes, you can generalize: If almost all $a_n$ have the same sign and $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ converges to a nonzero number, the claim still follows.

Comment: Here by "almost all" Hagen must mean all but finitely many (there are other possible interpretations). But every single sum-convergence theorem, not just this one, remains true if finitely many terms violate its hypotheses.

Answer (score 1):

You can relax the  assumptions to:     $b_n>0$   and $L\ne 0$. This way the test still works, for reason pointed out in comments: $a_n  $ will have the same sign as $L$ for large $n$.

If you drop the assumption $b_n>0$ and keep $a_n>0$, you will have to explain what to do with $a_n/b_n$ when $b_n=0$. If you add that $b_n\ne 0$, the test works fine.

If you drop all sign assumptions, the test fails. Here is one example: 
$$a_n= \frac{(-1)^n }{\sqrt{n}}; \quad b_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} +\frac{1}{2n} $$ 
Here $a_n/b_n\to 1$, but $\sum a_n $ converges while $\sum b_n$ diverges.